# raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (or any 404 status) for invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller controller, I have use `Date.new` to create a date object to be passed in my ActiveRecord.

```
end_range = Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i).end_of_day.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

The problem with this above is that if a user tried to change the parameters in the URL manually, such as entering `40` for the day param, the `Date.new` fails (as expected). However, I would rather not have a 500 error if a user typed in something like that, but instead a 404 error (because you will never actually be able a record with a day of `40`).

I tried various conditionals (`if` and `unless` statements) to `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if that fails, but it returns the 500 error before running the conditional (and therefor never returning a 404).

Does anybody know a better way to handle that, or a way to allow the `Date.new` to fail more gracefully so that the conditional statement can run?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this case you might rescue one exception and raise another if you'd like to re-map exceptions that aren't handled into the kind that are:

```
def show
  begin
    end_range = Date.new(...)
  rescue ArgumentError
    # Invalid date
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render(:partial => 'not_found', :layout => 'application', :status => :not_found)
end
```

It might be more efficient to simply render and fail right away though.

```
def show
  begin
    end_range = Date.new(...)
  rescue ArgumentError
    return render(:partial => 'date_not_found', :layout => 'application', :status => :not_found)
  end
end
```

You can also do this in a more sweeping sense using the `rescue_from` method of ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from 'ArgumentError do
    render(:partial => 'exceptions/argument_error', :layout => 'application', :status => :not_found)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The second example works great, that was what I was going for, but I started just trying to through an ActiveRecord NotFound just to get something other than 500. (If anybody reads, this, ActiveRecord is mistyped in the first example.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to rescue an invalid date error with a useful message. This is a common problem when people select 30 February for example. I would rather send them back to the form in question and tell them why they are getting sent back. A 404 would be wrong in most cases, since the error is invalid user input, not an invalid URL.

Further, if you rescue all `ArgumentError`s then you won't get notified of other code-related bugs. So if it's not a date error then I'm re-raising the error. Unfortunately we have to change the exception type to avoid a loop.

I've put this in the application_controller:

```
rescue_from ArgumentError do |exception|
  if exception.message == 'invalid date'
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to request.referer ? :back : root_url
  else
    raise StandardError, exception.message, exception.backtrace
  end
end
```

Comment: this answer is better, more Rails oriented!

Comment: StandardErrors are not recommended. They are just too basic and do not explain any context, only the fact that some exception has been raised.